# Why do I get "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, exception, input

When I enter my variable into the line I get the TypeError.

```
num = int(input("Enter a number"))
print("You are " + num * 7 + " dog years old")
```

I expect it to just take the input then multiply it by 7 and give the final number, but I just get the error. I barely understand str and int so an explanation of each would help too.

Comment: You cannot concatenate string and integer. See the documentation of string.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str


I think you are looking for something like:
`print("You are " + str(num * 7) + " dog years old")`

Comment: If you are using a recent python, you can do print(f"You are {num*7} dog years old")

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to a string:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number."))
print ("You are " + str(num * 7) + " dog years old")
```

As the error states, you cannot concatenate strings and ints:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects?